# Scrollable multi level horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I am trying to create a multi level scrollable horizontal  menu . The sub menu comes up fine upto n level but the scrollbar does not appear when the number of top level li items are more in number and cannot fit the page. Instead they start coming in the next line.

Below is the complete code

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">

   

 #nav, #nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
position:relative;
line-height:1.5em; 
}

#nav a{
display:block;
padding:0px 5px;
border:1px solid #333;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#333;
}

#nav a:hover{
background-color:#fff;
color:#333;
}

#nav li{
float:left;
position:relative;
}

#nav ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:12em;
top:1.5em;
}

#nav li ul a{
width:12em;
height:auto;
float:left;
}

#nav ul ul{
top:auto;
} 

#nav li ul ul {
left:12em;
margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
display:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
}




 </style>  
 </head>
 <body>
          <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3 Javascript</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">3.1 jQuery</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">3.1.1 New Download</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">3.1.2 New Tutorial</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">3.2 Mootools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3.3 Prototype</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>




         
            </ul>
     




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <style type="text/css">

   

 #nav, #nav ul{
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style-type:none;
list-style-position:outside;
position:relative;
line-height:1.5em; 
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
white-space: nowrap;
}

#nav a{
display:block;
padding:0px 5px;
border:1px solid #333;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
background-color:#333;
}

#nav a:hover{
background-color:#fff;
color:#333;
}

#nav li{
display: inline-block;
position:relative;
}

#nav ul {
position:absolute;
display:none;
width:12em;
top:1.5em;
}

#nav li ul a{
width:12em;
height:auto;
float:left;
}

#nav ul ul{
top:auto;
} 

#nav li ul ul {
left:12em;
margin:0px 0 0 10px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{
display:none;
}
#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul{
display:block;
}




 </style>  
 </head>
 <body>
          <ul id="nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">3 Javascript</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">3.1 jQuery</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">3.1.1 Download</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">3.1.1 New Download</a>

                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">3.1.2 New Tutorial</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">3.1.2 Tutorial</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">3.2 Mootools</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">3.3 Prototype</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1 HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2 CSS</a></li>




         
            </ul>
     




</body>
</html>
```

is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Alomost there..if you hover over the first li with the name Javascript we should be able to see the submenu with the list 'Jquey' and again its sub menu. Can you please tell me how to achieve that also. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer does not properly explain what the actual code solution was. Though the code is correct. I would like to point out this is most probably a height issue in the "nav" div. You should'nt put the height to auto. But rather keep it fixed so that the browser scrolls the rest. You could also try the "overflow" style to set the scroll on if the list is longer than the width.

Comment: Hi, The same thing is done below by Ron.basco but if I hover over the first li element wih the name 'javascript' I must be able to see its sub menu which is still not working. any idea how to achive that.